# Real analysis question for $b_{n+1} = a_{n}+a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Original question

- let  $b_{n}$ converge let $\lim b_{n}$ = b ,
- let  $b_{n+1}= a_{n}+a_{n+1}$
- prove that lim $\frac{a_{n}}{n} = 0$
- hint use $c_{n} = (-1)^{n}a_{n}$ and therefore $c_{n}-c_{n-1} = (-1)^{n}b_{n+1}$

I tried this styles to show this, my first attempt was to show odd and even subsequences of $(-1)^{n}b_{n+1}$ coverge to limit and then play around from there. So I got epsilon proofs for odd and even n's

for odd n, $$|c_{2n+1}|-|c_{2n+2}|-|b|\leq|c_{2n+1}-c_{2n+2}+b|<\epsilon'$$
for even n, $$|c_{2n}|-|c_{2n+1}|-|b|\leq|c_{2n}-c_{2n+1}-b|<\epsilon$$

This is where i get stuck on proceeding,

I tried subtracting and adding the sequences but i just hit a  dead end.

alternately i thought using the fact sequences are the odd and even sequneces converges therefore  $a_{2n}-a_{2n+2}$ converges and therefore this is cauchy for even n.

From this is say for even n let lim $a_{n}$ = a

so I can say that the limit of $a_{n}/n$ = a * (0) = 0 (as we can use a proposition that if the limit of a sequences is defined as the product limit of two sequences that each converge then it is the limit of their convergence).

we can do the same for odd n and therefore for all n an/n converges to zero.

**updated complete attempt 1,**

If a sequence is convergent then its absolute is also convergent. therefore $lim|(-1)^{n}b_{n}|$ converges

$lim(|c_{n}-c_{n+1}|) = lim |(-1)^{n}b_{n+1}| = lim( |b_{n}|)$.Therefore $lim(|c_{n}-c_{n+1}|)$ converges. All convergent sequences are bounded. Furthermore all Cauchy sequences are bounded because $lim(|c_{n}-c_{n+1}|)$ is bounded then ever member of this sequence is bounded . Therefore their exists a $Q$ such that, $|c_{n}|\leq Q$ where $Q\in\mathbb{R}$.

because $|c_{n}|=|a_{n}|$

therefore $0\leq lim (\frac{|a_{n}|}{n})=  lim (\frac{|c_{n}|}{n}) \leq lim(\frac{Q}{n}) = 0.$ Therefore by squeeze theorem $lim (\frac{|a_{n}|}{n}) = 0. $

Proposition......... $lim (\frac{|a_{n}|}{n}) = 0 \iff lim (\frac{a_{n}}{n}) = 0$

Comment: Write $c_n = c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k b_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Think about it this way: the fact that $c_{n+1}-c_n=(-1)^nb_{n+1}$ tells you that when $n$ is large, $c_{n+1}-c_n$ is approximately $(-1)^nb$. That is, the sequence $\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is almost oscillating between two values that differ by $b$ when $n$ is large enough. Use this to show that $|a_n|=|c_n|$ is bounded, and from that it follows readily that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n=0$.

Comment: is there a proof too show that if an absolute Cauchy sequence is convergent then all its members are bounded

Comment: thank you very much for your idea, I had thought of this originally but dropped the idea in favor of what i wrote above. Proof becomes very simple I think doing it your way

Comment: @ConradG: You’re welcome. Yes: every Cauchy sequence is bounded. If $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is Cauchy, there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<1$ whenever $n,m\ge n_0$. In particular, then $|x_n-x_{n_0}|<1$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Let $a=\max\{|x_k-x_{n_0}:k<n_0\}$, and let $b=\max\{a,1\}$; then $|x_k-x_{n_0}|\le b$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$, so $|x_k|\le|x_{n_0}|+b$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: I have updated the proof with an edit at the bottom. The only thing i am not so sure about is the part where I say $lim(|c_{n}−c_{n+1}|) $ being bounded implies $|c_{n}|$ is bounded. I can use reverse triangle to get $|c_{n}|\leq |c_{n+1}|+Q$. However I haven't shown that  is bounded, I simply said that this sequence is Cauchy therefore each of its member are Cauchy and therefore bounded. However I do feel I'm skipping here as as |c_{n}−c_{n+1}| is Cauchy not any  |c_{n}| therefore I cant determine if $|c_{n+1}|+Q$ is bounded.

Comment: sorry just saw that the max function alleviates the problem